# Flutter 2.0 pushAndRemoveUntil not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Not sure how to clear the stack and route to a new page after implementing the Flutter 2.0 routing.

The following isn't working:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInPage()), (route) => false);
```

`[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3075 pos 7: '!hasPage || isWaitingForExitingDecision': A page-based route cannot be completed using imperative api, provide a new list without the corresponding Page to Navigator.pages instead.`

Comment: wait, you are using `MaterialApp.router` together with `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil`?

Comment: I am. Do you know how to accomplish this type of behavior with MaterialApp.router ? It's essentially a log-out functionality -> bring the user to the sign-in screen and don't let them "go back" in the app.

Comment: the error says if you are using `MaterialApp.router` then you cannot use `pushAndRemoveUntil` ("navigator's imperative api") - instead you need to use router's api, more: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade

Comment: Sounds like there isn't a one-to-one alternative and that you need to essentially add a ChangeNotifier to your routing class that can be pulled in across your application. Then call a method into that that'll handle state updates across your router.
```class RoutePageManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  static RoutePageManager of(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider.of<RoutePageManager>(context, listen: false);
  }
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can access your MaterialApp navigator with rootNavigator: true. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/of.html.  Try the following it is working.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: 
true).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
SignInPage()), (route) => false);
```

Comment: Did not fix my issue with GoRouter, even when I change to "(route) => true" the exception disappears but I have another problem the screen is not pushedAndRemoveUntil really and I have the same screen twice in the widget tree above each other!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to pass the root name aswell.

Check my code i hope it might help you

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SignInPage()), ModalRoute.withName('/'),
```

Comment: Same error: `Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3075 pos 7: '!hasPage || isWaitingForExitingDecision': A page-based route cannot be completed using imperative api, provide a new list without the corresponding Page to Navigator.pages instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInPage()), (
    route) => false);
```

Comment: Same error: `Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3075 pos 7: '!hasPage || isWaitingForExitingDecision': A page-based route cannot be completed using imperative api, provide a new list without the corresponding Page to Navigator.pages instead.`

Comment: It's almost the same!

Answer (score 0):

when I implement route for android push Notification and use pushAndRemoveUntil  with

```
MaterialApp.router 
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

then not work so make (Route route) => false to true

```
MaterialApp.router 
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => true);
```

Answer (score -1):

To completely remove the stack, which disallows the user from navigating to the previous screen, you should use `PushReplacement`.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SigInPage()),
);
```

Comment: This does move the screen to the SignInPage but still let the user navigate back to where they were. I could hack a way around preventing back navigation by hiding the back button but that doesn't sound like the best approach.